# Typescript generics for array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to extend a generic list of Array which has been extended from my class.
How to do it properly?

```
export interface DeliveryMethod {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly company: string;
  readonly cost: number;
  readonly threshold: number;
  readonly intervals: Array<Interval>;
  readonly paymentMethods: Array<PaymentMethod>;
}

export interface Delivery {
  selected: SelectedDelivery;
  available: { [key : string] : Array<T extends DeliveryMethod>};
}
```

Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)

```
available: { [key : string] : Array<T extends DeliveryMethod>};
```

For example i need something like that:

```
const Delivery = {
   selected :{/*data inside*/},
   available:{
      pickup: [<Pickup>{},<Pickup>{}],
      courier: [<Courier>{},<Courier>{}]  
   }
}
```

Comment: `export interface Delivery<T>` - you need to declare your generic parameter.

Comment: @VLAZ its not working for my example.

Comment: Because I just wrote it too short, I suppose. I was trying to save space, I guess. `export interface Delivery<T extends DeliveryMethod>` - you should declare the generic parameter *with* its constraints as part of the interface declaration (or method/function declaration for a generic version of that when you have it). Once you've declared the parameter, you can then just use it within your interface as just the generic parameter name: `available: { [key : string] : Array<T>};`.

Comment: Could you not just have `Array<DeliveryMethod>`? I'm guessing anything that extends it would also work?

Comment: Do you **really** need a different type for Pickup and Courier?

Answer (score 3):

The @aopanasenko answer is fine. I want to complete it adding a way to solve the problem of multiple specifications.

If the properties of `available` aren't much, and they're fixed and stable, then you could think about listing them all in the `Delivery` interface:

```
interface Delivery<T extends DeliveryMethod, U extends DeliveryMethod> {
  available: { [key : string] : Array<T | U>};
};
```

Then you can define the `delivery` object like this:

```
const delivery: Delivery<Pickup, Courier>
```

If you don't know the properties a priori, then you need a way to link a property name to a TypeScript type, for example I added an `available` object just for the mapping:

```
interface Delivery {
  available: { [key: string]: Array<DeliveryMethod> | null };
};

const delivery: Delivery = {
  available: {}
}

const available: {
  pickup: Pickup[] | null,
  courier: Courier[] | null
} = {
  pickup: null,
  courier: null
};

delivery.available = { ...delivery.available, ...available };
```

In this way, it's correctly type-checked. I also added `| null` in order to provide an example, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

As mentioned by @AndreaSimoneCosta in comment the following code should work:

```js
export interface DeliveryMethod {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly company: string;
  readonly cost: number;
  readonly threshold: number;
  readonly intervals: Array<Interval>;
  readonly paymentMethods: Array<PaymentMethod>;
};

export interface Delivery<T extends DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethod> {
  selected: SelectedDelivery;
  available: { 
    [key : string] : Array<T>
  };
};
```

---

You should define generic type parameter list in angle brackets following the name of the `Delivery` interface:

```js
export interface DeliveryMethod {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly company: string;
  readonly cost: number;
  readonly threshold: number;
  readonly intervals: Array<Interval>;
  readonly paymentMethods: Array<PaymentMethod>;
};

export interface Delivery<T extends DeliveryMethod> {
  selected: SelectedDelivery;
  available: { 
    [key : string] : Array<T>
  };
};
```

Comment: But then he isn't able to have different types inside different arrays, as happens in his last example

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta, think types `Courier ` and `Pickup `  have the same structure with `DeliveryMethod `.

Comment: It's not going to work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQDbAG7QJ4CyEYAFgPYAmyA3gFDLJQRwVkgZ7LAUBcyAzmCigA5gG56jZq3acEZALYAHOCDx9BwkOMlMWbDsnmC+IAK4KARtAkM9Mw6Sb9yGXsnNWbtAL4TaoJCwiCgACsAIANZmSsgQAB6QIBT8aJg4+ESklDSSShHRSgBycAoQGkKivgHg0PBIyADCZGbC0HGJEMmp6Fi4UITE5FR0DPKtwNAlZRVaIvQ+tDVB9Si9GQMAPAAqHUkpaX2ZQ5QAfLkMcNhwwBhwlhjlNMgA2pEQnLOiALrIfACCUCgcDwO1Ofl8-nkIEEhw26nW-VB4SiMXOAF4Lpdrrd7o8eKMGET8qilHwXpsUYVTtQfAAaSkFNG0unfOmSIlGFptKDkzbNCbQGn0-ncyZQYW-ZAcxY+IA

Comment: And if you do like these, you could mix the types :( https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQDbAG7QJ4CyEYAFgPYAmyA3gFDLJQRwVkgZ7LAUBcyAzmCigA5gG56jZq3acEZALYAHOCDx9BwkOMlMWbDsnmC+IAK4KARtAkM9Mw6Sb9yGXsnNWbtAL4TaoJCwiCgACsAIANZmSsgQAB6QIBT8aJg4+ESklDSSShHRSgBycAoQGkKivgHg0PBIyADCZGbC0HGJEMmp6Fi4UITE5FR0DPKtwNAlZRVaIvQ+tDVB9Si9GQMAPAAqHUkpaX2ZQzkAvIcbg9kUAHy5DHDYcMAYcJYY5TTIANqREJyzUQAXWQfAAglAoHA8Dsbn5fP55CBBBd+up1mjkOdRg8ni83h8eDiGAx8lEYnxvptwuSlDdqD4ADTUgoxelMzbNCbQdlAxmSElGFptKCUznCyZQdnMrki6Us2m8hgCxY+IA

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta what's mean expression  <T extends DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethod>?

Comment: @AndreaSimoneCosta, thanks for pointing out inaccuracies in my answer. I updated an answer with link to your comment.

Comment: @aopanasenko you're welcome. But the problem, the fact that you will be able to mix the types, remains. Something like `pickup: [<Pickup>{},<Pickup>{},<Courier>{}]` will be valid for TS, because it sees `DeliveryMethod`s. And the fact that they are all `DeliveryMethod`s will prevent us to treat them more precisely.

Comment: I think that several stuff should be refactored, starting from that `[key : string]`.

Comment: @Иван Яковлев `T extends DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethod` means that `T` should be assignable to `DeliveryMethod` and, if you don't provide a `T`, `DeliveryMethod' will be used as **default type value**.